# Using YQL, how would you access certain elements of a requested webpage when it is returned as JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, yql

Just using a random example with [this webpage](http://ftw.usatoday.com/2014/12/nike-new-uniforms-college-football-playoff) how would I be able to access and use the articleBody element of the page and then get the individual paragraph elements of the the articleBody? Meaning how would I get the paragraph elements as a string.

Comment: Why not set up a jsFiddle for us, as getting the JSON from YQL into the fiddle would be most of the work we need to do to even get started ?

Comment: That's a fail, syntax error!

Comment: In this case, when you're looking for certain elements, using the XML option in YQL is probably easier, as you can do this -> **http://jsfiddle.net/30tmwokb/**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/30tmwokb/1/

Comment: @adeneo how would i then access the string in the document and is the use of yql still necessary since i used it to get around the Same Domain javascript policy?

Comment: Why not try it out, log the data to the console, and see if you can figure it out ?

Comment: @adeneo yeah you still have to use yql but i tried printing p (the variable for the paragraphs in articleBody) but it didnt work and said that it was undefined, how would you get the data in p.

Comment: Did you see my example above, doesn't that get the text in the paragraphs ?

Comment: @adeneo it does but it prints the text to the document not assigning it to any variable, and on a side note dude thanks so much for your help

Comment: If you haven't read it, you should -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: And getting the text to a variable would just be something like -> **http://jsfiddle.net/30tmwokb/2/**